# Is it possible to remove lock screen on Android 7/Nougat?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat

In earlier versions of Android (<6) there was an option to have screen lock as none. Couldn't see the same option on Nougat. Is it even possible in Android 7?

Comment: Settings->Security, Under Device Security, tap on screen lock and select None.(It allows you to unlock device directly to home screen)

Comment: I don't think that exists in Nougat any more.